# HTMLStripCharFilterFactory apparently not working, still retrieving xml tags

Tags: xml, search, solr

HTMLStripCharFilterFactory shows xml tags striped in query analyser but when i check in browser using search command its not stripping XML tags.

its working when I analyse the query in .../admin/analysis.jsp but when i try to see the search results it shows the XML back in.

```
<analyzer type="index">
                <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
```

...

and query analyser is

```
 <analyzer type="query">
                              <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
```

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Analysis page shows the index time analysis and hence you don't see the xml tags as they are stripped by the HTML Strip filter.

However, when you run the search command Solr will return the stored results only.
It does not return the indexed data. Indexed data is only used for searching.

Comment: Thanks for reply, just want to understand what exactly is happening, if i want that only striped data should be stored or indexed. is it possible? i tried HTMLStripTransformer as well but here is problem in it. can i use <charFilter in order to just ignore all the tags and give solr only the data to be indexed or stored.

Comment: The data will be striped before being indexed. However, Solr does not modify the data stored which is different from one that is indexed. So you will always get the original data back in search results. IF you want the striped data returned you need to handle it from client side.